# Assigning node-set to xsl:variable from iterating an xml with if condition

Tags: xslt, xpath

I write this code for assigning node-set to xsl:variable

```
<xsl:variable name="disableSelected">
    <xsl:for-each select="rejectSignatureType">
        <xsl:if test="disableInd = 'true'">
            <xsl:value-of select="@signatureTypeId"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

but instead of node-set it is returning string value. Here is the sample XML I am traversing.

```
<rejectSignatureType signatureTypeId="closeActionSignaturetypeId1">      
    <disableInd>true</disableInd>
</rejectSignatureType>
<rejectSignatureType signatureTypeId="closeActionSignaturetypeId2">      
    <disableInd>false</disableInd>
</rejectSignatureType>
<rejectSignatureType signatureTypeId="closeActionSignaturetypeId3">      
    <disableInd>true</disableInd>
</rejectSignatureType>
```

can some one help how to return node-set in `xsl:variable`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single XPath expression:

```
<xsl:variable name="disableSelected"
    select="rejectSignatureType[disableInd = 'true']/@signatureTypeId"/>
```

That would set the variable to a node set containing all the relevant `signatureTypeId` attribute nodes.